# Adding a parameter block to a function

Tags: c, struct

Yesterday I had a problem with a function, turned out I forgot to declare a variable of the structure type, it is clear now what was the problem. I've modified my code, and I got another error messages, however it looks like the code actually s working.
I googled the problem but I can't really  fit the solutions to my code. Can somebody shows and explain me what would be the clean way of the below code?

```
#include  <stdio.h>

/*************************************************
include
**************************************************/
//A signal structure
typedef struct SIGNAL_STRUCTURE
{
    int id;
    int time;
}signal_structure;

//Structure what collects all the signals 
typedef struct SIGNAL_COLLECTOR
{
    signal_structure EngSpeed;
    signal_structure TransReqGear;
    signal_structure CurrentGear;
}signal_collector;

//Function to do with the above structure
void ManipulateSignal(signal_structure * signal)
{
    signal->id = 10;
    signal->time = 11;
}

/*************************************************
main
**************************************************/
void fcn(signal_collector * param_signal, int len)
{
    int *pointer = param_signal;
   
    while(len--)
    {
        ManipulateSignal(pointer);
        pointer += (sizeof(signal_structure) / sizeof(int));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    signal_collector foo;
    fcn(&foo, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you don't understand what a compiler error means, [look it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=expected+expression+before+).

Comment: Ok, that is clear now, but there is another I tried to look it up, but it does not help, I found nothing useful. [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a typedef name as a function argument. You need to declare a variable with that type, and pass the address of the variable.

```
int main(void) {
    param_collector my_pc;
    fcn(&my_pc);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass the reference to the object, but you forgot to define this object.

```
int main(void)
{
    param_collector param_collector;
    fcn(&param_collector);
    return 0;
}
```

but I would give rather call the variable a distinct name (not the same as type)